# ATTiny85 Use external crystal for timer but not system clock

Tags: crystal, attiny, attiny85

I'm working on a project using an ATTiny85 where I need a precise timer. I have some 32kHz crystals, which it looks like would work fine if I ran the system clock off of them and made the timer take system clock input. The issue is that the rest of the application isn't going to work running at such a low frequency.

So the main question I have: Is there some way I can use these crystals as input to the timer, without also clocking the whole system off of them? I know there's the timer input pin, but I don't know what extra circuitry I'd need to support it.

I realize the simplest solution is just going to be buying a higher frequency crystal, but I'm interested in seeing if there's some way to work with what I have (particularly if it can save me a pin).

Comment: an external crystal takes two pins, clock input takes only one pin,  how are you "saving a pin" by using the crystal?

Comment: What does the data sheet say? Is it for example possible to run the system with the internal oscillator, and the timer with the external low-frequency oscillator? There should be some application note for the clock system too.

Comment: @thebusybee Unfortunately the external crystal/clock inputs go directly into the system clock. There is a separate timer input pin which is what I was thinking of using, but it's only a single pin - hence me asking what else I'd need to make it support a crystal.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an old-school CD4000 series Schmitt-trigger inverter. I think the CD40106 is an option. The datasheet should have a crystal oscillator circuit.

Or, look up 32.768kHz pierce oscillator.

Comment: Both interesting options, thanks. Looks like I need to buy some new parts either way, but seems simple enough in return for freeing up a pin.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be some timekeeping application, have a look into I²C and SPI RTCs as well. They have a 32kHz oscillator on board, often the caps as well, and often feature a reset or event switch debounce circuit and clock and interrupt outputs. Or battery failover and trickle charging. All for less than a dollar.